# start chrome packaged app in fullscreen mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

Im working on a chrome app, currently testing it using developer mode. Im trying to open my app in full screen whenever user click on app shortcut (chrome -> Apps -> MYAPP). I've managed to do this on button click using requestFullScreen() method but it can only be done when user loads the app and click on fullscreen button. What i want is to launch the app in fullscreen mode. Is it possible to convert that onClick eventlistner to onLoad?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set the [`state`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#property-options-state) option to `"fullscreen"` when calling [`chrome.app.window.create`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#method-create). Note that you will also need to declare [`fullscreen`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions.html#fullscreen) permission in the app manifest.

Comment: Thnx for your reply Ken. The thing is im able to open page in fullscreen but it can only happen when user clicks on the link. Im trying to open the page in fullscreen mode on onLoad event not onClick. I copied the onClick code and just converted it to onLoad event and nothing happens, even thought onClick code works perfect. I googled it and it says fullscreen require user conscent and therefore cannot be open on onLoad eventlister.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question no longer makes sense to me. Are you writing a packaged app? If this just is a hosted app, you will not be able to enter fullscreen on load.

Comment: @KenRockot I'm making a hosted app and I can't figure out a way to make it auto open to fullscreen